# How to merge CSV files but the data in each csv has different position?

Tags: python, pandas

I have many CSV files in one folder and these CSV files have different names with no regularity. I want to merge them in one by Python.

These CSVs have the same columns, but some of the files start with different positions because the first few raws are occupied with information and also the bottom has messages as well.

For example, one file's data starts from A6 because A1 to A5 has information and the bottom also has message, and some of the file's data start from A5 and the bottom message ends depending on the data.

How can I merge these CSV files into one dataframe ? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a DataFrame from each CSV like you would normally do with [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Then, loop through each DataFrame using [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) until you find the string "Date" (your first column header) and a string that contains the word "Total" (which is your message at the bottom of the CSV). Then simply slice the DataFrame so you only keep the data in between these rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if row[0] == "Date":
      start_row = index
   elif "Total" in row[0]:
      end_row = index

new_df = df.iloc[start_row:end_row]
```

If you have multiple CSV files in one folder, you can use [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to loop through them and apply the code above. If you add the DataFrame of each iteration to a list, and use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) you can merge them into one DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

list_files = list(pathlib.Path("path_to_your_folder").glob('*.csv'))
list_df = []

for index, csv in enumerate(list_files):
   df = pd.read_csv(csv)

   for index, row in df.iterrows():
      if row[0] == "Date":
         if index == 0:
            start_row = index
         elif:
            start_row = index+1
      elif "Total" in row[0]:
         end_row = index

   new_df = df.iloc[start_row:end_row]
   list_df.append(new_df)

df_out = pd.concat(list_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works for a single file, I have got too many CSV files like this.

Comment: You can simply loop through the CSV files and apply the code. I've added an example using Pathlib for you

Comment: Thank you, it looks work but it tells me I have to transfer the percentage into a string type first.

Comment: I guess this is about the last column "Efficient"? You can try to replace the line in which you read the CSV with this, but I haven't tested it: `df = pd.read_csv(csv, dtype={"Efficient": str})`. This should read the values containing the percentages as strings.

Comment: It is still no working. But I tried `df = df.astype(str)` underneath `df = pd.read_csv(csv)`, it works a little but only shows one csv result, it doen't merge all csv files.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that you wanted to merge them all together. I've updated my post, hope it works like this!

Comment: Thanks, the output merges two tables indeed, however, it doesn't eliminate 2nd table's columns names, the columns names from 2nd table display after merging.

Comment: That's because the code says that the "start_row" variable should be the line with the word "Date" in it, but this should only be the case for the first iteration (because you only need the column names ones). You can fix this by using an if-statement. I've updated the code